# Фраймворк Codeignither. Что означает строчка?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ребят подскажите что означает эта строчка только по русски)

```
$query = $this->db->select('id, title')->get_where('tm_subcategory', array('id_category' => 5));
```

Comment: из таблицы `tm_subcategory` получает запись с ключем `id_category` `5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать выборку из БД: выбрать все строки из таблицы tm_subcategory где поле id_category равно 5. При этом из всех колонок в выборке только колонки id и title.